# Is there a difference between provoking an Opportunity Attack (OA) and being the target of an OA?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, opportunity-attack, targeting, mounted-combat

Based on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149426/5e-mounted-combatant-and-mobile-how-do-these-feats-interact-re-opportunity-att) regarding the interaction of Mounted Combatant and Mobile Feats, there seems to be a possible loophole regarding provoking an OA and being the target of an OA.

Does the redirected attack from Mounted Combatant mean that the mount provokes the OA, but the rider just becomes a target of an attack? Or is the OA and its target always coupled?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference is or why it matters. What's the loophole you are referring to?

Comment: No I totally get that connection. It just seems like this question is asking the same question but in a general context as opposed to a specific case context like the linked question does.

Comment: Fair enough! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, there is a difference but it rarely comes into play

First of all, the rules tell us under what conditions you provoke an opportunity attack (OA):

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature.

So, a creature provokes an attack when they move out of your reach. You are then able to choose to target the creature with a melee attack.

Here is the first indication that the two are separate: the creature provokes and *then*  you get to decide if you want to target them. You can ignore the provoke, or you might be unable to act on it (eg you don't have a reaction left). Either way, the provoking comes before and separate from the targeting. Normally, though it doesn't matter since usually a) provoked OA that cannot be acted on are just ignored or b) the creature being targeted by the OA is the one who provoked the OA.

There are some cases where the latter case is not true, for example the case of a mounted rider whose mount has provoked an OA:

> if the mount provokes an opportunity attack while you’re on it, the
> attacker can target you or the mount

Here again is evidence that provoking the OA and targeting with the OA are different. First the mount provokes the OA, then the creature gets to decide which of you it wants to target (or if they don't want to take it).

So, from everything the rules indicates, provoking an OA and being the target of an OA are different things.

Comment: I think this is right and it definitely invalidates my answer to the linked question :) I hadn't really thought of it like that. It again shows the power of the Disengage action.